# How to show unique values in a column in SQL/Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have an advanced query in which I would like to show unique values of the column "`vq5p1.message`". How can I do this?

My Query:

```
SELECT th.hashtag_id,
       COUNT(th.hashtag_id) as count_hashtags, vq5p1.message
  FROM tweet_hashtag th
  JOIN tweet t
    ON t.tweet_id = th.tweet_id
  JOIN virtualq5p1 vq5p1
    ON vq5p1.tweet_id = th.tweet_id
  JOIN hashtag_fc fc
    ON fc.hashtag_id = vq5p1.hashtag_id
  JOIN game g
    ON g.fc_id1 = fc.fc_id
    OR g.fc_id2 = fc.fc_id 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM virtualq5p1 vq5p2
                    WHERE vq5p2.hashtag_id = th.hashtag_id
                      AND vq5p2.tweet_id = th.tweet_id)
   AND t.created_time >= g.official_start
   AND t.created_time <= g.official_end
GROUP BY th.hashtag_id, vq5p1.message
ORDER BY COUNT(th.hashtag_id) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Note:** vq5p1 is a view.

Right now I am only getting duplicate results that are not correct:

[Screenshot of what I am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxRFl.png)

Comment: You are grouping by `th.hashtag_id` as well - do you expect each unique `vq5p1.message` to be mapped to one unique `th.hashtag_id`? If yes, maybe re-evaluate your join statement

Comment: Yes @ Anna. I'll try that then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So in order to get the unique messages, I created a view of the following:

```
SELECT th.hashtag_id,
       COUNT(th.hashtag_id) as count_hashtags, vq5p1.message
  FROM tweet_hashtag th
  JOIN tweet t
    ON t.tweet_id = th.tweet_id
  JOIN virtualq5p1 vq5p1
    ON vq5p1.tweet_id = th.tweet_id
  JOIN hashtag_fc fc
    ON fc.hashtag_id = vq5p1.hashtag_id
  JOIN game g
    ON g.fc_id1 = fc.fc_id
    OR g.fc_id2 = fc.fc_id 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM virtualq5p1 vq5p3
                    WHERE vq5p3.hashtag_id = th.hashtag_id
                      AND vq5p3.tweet_id = th.tweet_id)
   AND t.created_time >= g.official_start
   AND t.created_time <= g.official_end
GROUP BY th.hashtag_id, vq5p1.message
ORDER BY COUNT(th.hashtag_id) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And then use the result from the view and the table where the original 'message' column was.

```
select vq5p2.hashtag_id, vq5p2.count_hashtags, ht.message
from hashtag ht
JOIN virtualq5p2 vq5p2
ON vq5p2.hashtag_id = ht.hashtag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT vq5p1.message, COUNT(*) as count_hashtags
. . .
GROUP BY vq5p1.message
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This will return one row per message with the number of hash tags assigned to it (I think).